# Java: Delete mysql row if value doesn't exist in ArrayList

Tags: java, mysql, sql

My table:

```
-----------------
|name   |   age |
-----------------
 john        45
 maria       31
 george      24
 Toby        46
 Emmalee     55
 Simeon      16
 Gustavo     71
 Hamza       64
      ...
```

Well lets say I have an ArrayList with 40 ints inside but with random integers.
I want to run a query that will delete all rows from my table but not those who their age is inside of my arraylist... how I supposed to do that?
Sorry for my English. i'm using google translate

My code:

```
List<Integer> myList;
private static final String databaseQuery = "DELETE FROM users WHERE age ??";

try (Connection con = Database.getInstance().getLocalConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(databaseQuery)) 
{
    ps.executeUpdate();
}
catch (SQLException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I don't know how to start the query... I think its more java than sql..

 Updated..... better now?

Answer (score 3):

```
try (PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(
        "DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE age NOT IN (?)")) {
    Object[] ageArray = ageList.toArray();
    Array array = connection.createArrayOf("INT", ageArray);
    pstmt.setArray(1, array);
    int updateCount = pstmt.executeUpdate();
}
```

There is a SQL Array class for such a purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I can help you with some logic thinking.
Well the first thing you need to do is query the database (Select * from tableName) and save the results, next you need to nested two cycles, one is the results from query and another is the said ArrayList (while, do while or a simple for) then in each iteration you need to compare the row that you were in with the iteration of the ArrayList, if it is a match you should delete that element from DB.
Hope I could help you with some logic.

Comment: Thank for your hints but this way needs as much connections as the columns to be deleted :D am I wrong?

Comment: No you don't. You just need to make a connection to database  (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html) and then create some querys (when items match) to execute on said connection. A good example, you still need to implement your structure there. https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/sql/delete-table-row-example/